# Create series of tuples from pandas DataFrame efficiently

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using `apply()` to construct a Series of tuples from the values of an existing DataFrame. I need to construct a specific order of the values in the tuple, and replace `NaN` in all but one column with `'{}'`.

The following functions work to produce the desired result, but the execution is rather slow:

```
def build_insert_tuples_series(row):
    # Here I attempt to handle ordering the final tuple
    # I must also replace NaN with "{}" for all but v2 column.
    vals = [row['v2']]
    row_sans_v2 = row.drop(labels=['v2'])
    row_sans_v2.fillna("{}", inplace=True)
    res = [val for val in row_sans_token]
    vals += res
    return tuple(vals)

def generate_insert_values_series(df):
    df['insert_vals'] = df.apply(lambda x: build_insert_tuples_series(x), axis=1)
    return df['insert_vals']
```

Original DataFrame:

```
    id   v1    v2
0  1.0  foo  quux
1  2.0  bar   foo
2  NaN  NaN   baz
```

Resulting DataFrame upon calling `generate_insert_values_series(df)`:

The logic for order on the final tuple is `(v2, ..all_other_columns..)`

```
    id   v1    v2       insert_vals
0  1.0  foo  quux  (quux, 1.0, foo)
1  2.0  bar   foo   (foo, 2.0, bar)
2  NaN  NaN   baz     (baz, {}, {})
```

Timing the function to generate the resulting DataFrame:

```
%%timeit
generate_insert_values_series(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop
```

I feel that there may be a way to more efficiently construct the Series, but am unsure of how to optimize the operation using vectorization, or another approach.

Comment: What's the logic for the order in the final tuple?

Comment: Updated question: Logic for order on the final tuple is `(v2, ..all_other_columns..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `zip`, `get`, `mask`, `fillna`, and `sorted`

One liner for what it's worth

```
df.assign(
    insert_vals=
    [*zip(*map(df.mask(df.isna(), {}).get, sorted(df, key=lambda x: x != 'v2')))])

    id   v1    v2       insert_vals
0  1.0  foo  quux  (quux, 1.0, foo)
1  2.0  bar   foo   (foo, 2.0, bar)
2  NaN  NaN   baz     (baz, {}, {})
```

Less one-liner-ish

```
get = df.mask(df.isna(), {}).get
key = lambda x: x != 'v2'
cols = sorted(df, key=key)

df.assign(insert_vals=[*zip(*map(get, cols))])

    id   v1    v2       insert_vals
0  1.0  foo  quux  (quux, 1.0, foo)
1  2.0  bar   foo   (foo, 2.0, bar)
2  NaN  NaN   baz     (baz, {}, {})
```

---

This should work for legacy python

```
get = df.mask(df.isna(), {}).get
key = lambda x: x != 'v2'
cols = sorted(df, key=key)

df.assign(insert_vals=zip(*map(get, cols)))
```

Comment: Looks great - I think this unpacking syntax perhaps works only for python 3?

Comment: I've updated my post with something that works in python 2

Comment: Excellent, just one minor edit here for my purposes: `get = df.mask(df.isna(), "{}").get`

Comment: @WesDoyle I thought that was a dictionary literal.  In that case, you can use `get = df.fillna("{}").get`

Comment: Ah, thank you - I updated my question to reflect `'{}'`

Answer (score 2):

First you can use `numpy` to replace `null` values by the `dicts`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2, None], 'v1':['foo', 'bar', None], 'v2':['quux', 'foo', 'bar']})

def replace_na(col): 
    return np.where(temp[col].isnull(), '{}', temp[col])

def generate_tuple(df):
    df['id'], df['v1'] = replace_na('id'), replace_na('v1')
    return df.apply(lambda x: tuple([x['v2'], x['id'], x['v1']]), axis=1)
```

Your gain is

```
%%timeit
temp['insert_tuple'] = generate_tuple(temp)
>>>> 1000 loops, best of 3 : 1ms per loop
```

If you change the `generate_tuple return` to something like

```
def generate_tuple(df):
    df['id'], df['v1'] = replace_na('id'), replace_na('v1')
    return list(zip(df['v2'], df['id'], df['v1']))
```

your gain becomes:

```
%%timeit
temp['insert_tuple'] = generate_tuple(temp)
1000 loops, best of 3 : 674 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't *want* to do this, as your new series will lose all vectorised functionality.

But, if you must, you can avoid `apply` here by using either [`pd.DataFrame.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), a list comprehension, or `map`. The only complication is reordering columns, which you can do via conversion to `list`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

col_lst = df.columns.tolist()
cols = [col_lst.pop(col_lst.index('v2'))] + col_lst

%timeit list(df[cols].itertuples(index=False))  # 31.3 ms per loop
%timeit [tuple(x) for x in df[cols].values]     # 74 ms per loop
%timeit list(map(tuple, df[cols].values))       # 73 ms per loop
```

Benchmarking above is on Python 3.6.0, but you are likely to find these more efficient than `apply` even on 2.7. Note that `list` conversion is not necessary for the final version, since `map` returns a `list` in v2.7.

If absolutely necessary, you can `fillna` via a series:

```
s = pd.Series([{} for _ in range(len(df.index))], index=df.index)

for col in df[cols]:
    df[cols].fillna(s)
```